# How can I prevent certain system tests from including a module included in all system tests by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added a functionality for users to log in to my Rails app. I used Rails' generator to generate a scaffold for users, which created [`UsersTest`](https://github.com/mgoks/bookstore/blob/main/test/system/users_test.rb) system tests. I also added an `authorize` method to [`ApplicationController`](https://github.com/mgoks/bookstore/blob/main/app/controllers/application_controller.rb) in order to authorize to users before performing actions. To log in during test runs, I created the module [`ActionDispatch`](https://github.com/mgoks/bookstore/blob/56ef806a204c5f0856fa6a1491b8f1be0def1e75/test/test_helper.rb#L19) to take care of logging in and out. (*ActionDispatch* might be a bad name but that is the same name the author used in the book *Agile Web Dev with Rails 7*.)

The problem is that now user system tests do not work. The app requires the test agent to log in but it does not log in (which might mean that the test helper is not included in those tests?). I guess this might be solved by adding the log-in code to `UsersTest` manually but the book writes

> The system test in test/system/users_test.rb was generated by the scaffolding generator we used at the start of the chapter. Those tests don’t pass. See if you can get them to pass without breaking the other system tests. You’ll recall we created the module AuthenticationHelpers and included it in all of the system tests by default, so you might need to change the code to not do that so that you can properly test the login functionality.

So how can I exclude AuthenticationHelpers (ActionDispatch) from `UsersTest`?

I added `skip_before_action :authorize` to UsersTest but it didn't work.

> Development/depot/test/system/users_test.rb:6:in `class:UsersTest': undefined method `skip_before_action' for UsersTest:Class (NoMethodError)

[It looks like I can only use that method in controllers.](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/issues/396#issuecomment-289554287)

Comment: according to the book excerpt that you shared, you need not to exclude AuthenticationHelpers but change its code. Also, ActionDispatch is a rails built-in class, it's likely that the (very well-regarded) authors of the book are overwriting some methods in ActionDispatch, this is something that is possible and acceptable in Ruby.

Comment: What kind of a change do I need to make? @LesNightingill